# I need to preg_replace some parts of text

Tags: php

I need to replace some parts of text, example:

```
"I like this car, but that car is good"
```

So lets say i need replace "this car" with

```
"<u>this car</u>".
```

which is not problem

```
str_replace('this car','<u>this car</u>',$line)
```

This will replace all matches.

Now I need to replace single "car"  which is not underline already with

```
<b>car</b>
```

and thats where I stack.

so what is happening, i am doing 1st replacement and getting text:

```
"I like <u>this car</u>, but that car is good"
```

if i will do

```
str_replace('car','<b>car</b>',$line)
```

i will end up with this :

```
"I like <u>this <b>car<b></u>, but that <b>car</b> is good"
```

which is not good because 1st match car already underlined.

Please suggest

Comment: It's not exactly the solution you want but you could always use CSS to un-bold the underlined `<b>` tag ~ `ul b { font-weight: normal; }`

Comment: No, I need actual html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`strtr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) for this job, as it will replace longer matches first and then shorter ones, ignoring anything that it has already done a replacement on. For example:

```
$string = "I like this car, but that car is good";
echo strtr($string, array('this car' => '<u>this car</u>', 'car' => '<b>car</b>'));
```

Output:

```
I like <u>this car</u>, but that <b>car</b> is good
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/behmN)

Comment: Thanks! How to close this question now ? =)

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
str_replace('this car','<u>this <b>car</b></u>',$line)
```